# add script on boot linux machine

Tags: linux, bash

I have one script to start a service on my ubuntu. I added it on boot machine using "# update-rc.d projeto defaults". But it still doesn't start with the boot machine. I think is because I am using other user to start the script "su - www-data -c ...". But I am not sure, because I run the update-rc.d command as root. When I execute the script from a terminal, it asks the password of the user www-data.

Does anyone know what is happening?
Thanks a lot!
Felipe

```
#!/bin/bash
# /var/www/boinc/projeto/bin/start

function action {
        su - www-data -c "/var/www/boinc/projeto/bin/$1"
}

case $1 in
        start|stop|status)
        action $1
        ;;
        *)
        echo "ERRO: usar $0 (start|stop|status)"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Doesn't the `-c` option need to go before `- user`?

Comment: No, didn't work with the -c before - user

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script with sleep function between the commands and it worked...

```
#!/bin/bash
# /var/www/boinc/projeto/bin/start

su - www-data -c "/var/www/boinc/projeto/bin/stop"
sleep 20
su - www-data -c "/var/www/boinc/projeto/bin/start"
```

Comment: You can even accept your own answers... (but maybe only after a certain time)